How to render a dynamic html template across multiple pages with header and footer?
Im working on a project where I need to print rendered HTML to a PDF. The content of the HTML is fairly dynamic, and I need to maintain a fixed content size per page, along with rendering of header and footer at each printed page.
This is an example setup of the HTML to be printed:
<div *ngIf="report">
  <front-page></>
  <static-content-page-1></>
  <static-content-page-2></>
  <dynamic-content-page-1></>
  <static-content-page-3></>
  <dynamic-content-page-2></>
</div>

The front page and pages with static content are fine, and this is a simple example of them:
<page-layout>
  //Hardcoded HTML
</page-layout>

The page-layout looks like this:
<div class="single-page">
  <div class="simulated-page-break top"></div>
  <pdf-header></pdf-header>
  <div class="page-content">
    <ng-content></ng-content>
  </div>
  <pdf-footer [page]="page" [totalPages]="totalPages"></pdf-footer>
  <div class="simulated-page-break bottom"></div>
</div>

The simulated page breaks are just for visual help during development.
CSS:
.single-page {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 798px;
  height: 1126px;
  page-break-after: always;
  break-inside: avoid;
  overflow: visible;
  background-color: white;
}

.page-content {
  width: 698px;
  height: 954px;
  padding: 50px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  break-inside: avoid;
}

Now, the CSS of the single-page and page-content works perfectly for printing, but as you can see, I had to define the height of each to be able to make the pages break at the correct height for the PDF printing.
The problem arises for the pages containing dynamic content. The dynamic content consists of some static column headers, page titles etc, and a mix of different custom components that vary a lot in terms of rendered height.
For these pages, I need to make sure that the dynamic content is split out across multiple instances of the page whenever the total content height exceeds the height defined in the page-content (954px).
I have been able to implement a somewhat working implementation already, where I first render all content inside a hidden container, and then use this as a base for dividing content out into multiple pages, but it is too rigid and dependent on pre-defining the dynamic elements in order to make it work for more complex HTML structures. The more I dig into this rabbit hole of a solution, the more I feel that I'm doing it unnecessarily complicated and "hacky".
So simply put: What would be the most "angularistic" way of dividing dynamic content with dynamic height across multiple pages, while maintaining a fixed header, footer, and content size per page ?

I'm not sure if that is a solution. As I said, the dynamic content consists of a wide array of custom angular components, with dynamic data binding, images, etc.

@SveinMathisen please replicate the issue on this stackblitz and update on the question for checking
